# Foundation 5 Range slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Hey i've been trying out some things with the range sliders in Foundation 5. I'm trying to assign the sum of the range sliders to another range slider but it doesn't look right. New to this framework so i'm a little confused. Heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae5Y4/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">

        <div class="range-slider" id="slider1" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 500; display_selector: #SliderOutput1;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"></div>
        <div id="SliderOutput1"></div>
        <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 250; display_selector: #SliderOutput2;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"> </div>
        <div id="SliderOutput2"></div>
        <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 200; display_selector: #SliderOutput3;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"> </div>
        <div id="SliderOutput3"></div>


    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">

        <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 500; display_selector: #SliderOutput4;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"> </div>
        <div id="SliderOutput4"></div>
        <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 500; display_selector: #SliderOutput5;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"> </div>
        <div id="SliderOutput5"></div>
        <div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 200; display_selector: #SliderOutput6;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"></div>
        <div id="SliderOutput6"></div>


<br/><br/>

        <input type="button" value="sum" id="sum" />

        <div id="myResults"></div>
        <div class="range-slider-total" data-slider data-options="start: 1; end: 2250; display_selector: #SliderOutput7;"> <span class="range-slider-handle"></span> <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span> <input type="hidden"></div>
        <div id="SliderOutput7"></div>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).foundation();


  function doMath()
{
    var sum = 0;
    $('.range-slider').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr('data-slider'));
    });
    document.getElementById('myResults').innerHTML = sum;

    var new_value = sum;
    $('.range-slider-total').foundation('slider', 'set_value', new_value);
}
 $("#sum").click(doMath);
```

Comment: i think someone downvoted your question because its title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It's broken because you broke it by replacing `range-slider` class with the the `range-slider-total`. Just use different selector in the js and return old class.

Comment: Hey i took your advice, seems to be working like how i want it now, heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae5Y4/8/